# Passing answers from a Dialog to a JavaScript

Tags: html, google-apps-script, modal-dialog

I'm making a spreadsheet. I want it to have a button (I have already done this). Clicking this button should open a dialog with an editable numeric field, two checkboxes, and OK, Cancel buttons.

Of course, when the OK button is pressed, some things should happen in the spreadsheet, that is, I want pass the information that the user entered in the dialog to the script that opened the dialog.

I have been looking in GAS guides and reference and I found nothing (the [example in the guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) has only a button to close the dialog: no information is passed). A complete example would be most helpful.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm new here, and I thought that this StackOverFlow page were more specific. My question is about Google Apps Script, and the spreadsheet I'm making is a Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I assume you already have at least the `Code.gs` and `Index.html` from the example. What you should do is define your custom handlers in your `Code.gs` file to handle the data you send from the HTML Service

To make it easy, we'll suppose all you want to do is insert a new row with some text. So we'll start by creating the handler:

```
// Code.gs
function createNewRow(text) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(['New row', text]);
}
```

Then, put some custom HTML elements and the Javascript code to make the link:

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" value="Insert new row" onclick="insertNewRow()" />
<script>
function insertNewRow(){
  // Calls our handler with the value of the input with id "text"
  google.script.run.createNewRow(document.querySelector('#text').value);
}
</script>
```

That would be all. I hope it's an easy enough example for you to follow